# Send Collection in .NET that matches a string?

Tags: c#, .net

I have about 27 collections in my program. I have a button that corresponds to each of these collections with a "Tag" on that button.

```
<MenuItem Header="Collection 01" Tag="collection01" Click="collection_Click" />
```

When I click on this item, I would like for it to call up a new window with the contents of the collection to which it is tagged. How would I extract the tag, and have it send the collection?

```
private void collection_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem item = (MenuItem)sender;

    CollectionEdit dataEdit = new CollectionEdit(item.Tag.ToString());
}
```

Doing what I have above, sends the string "collection01", but not collection01 itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself using reflections:

```
CollectionEdit dataEdit = new CollectionEdit((ObservableCollection<string>)this.GetType().GetField(item.Tag.ToString()).GetValue(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `collection01`, `collection02`, `collection03`, etc, you should put the collections in a `collections` array... a collection of collections if you will. Then you can put the collection index in the `Tag` property and access it that way:

```
private void collection_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem item = (MenuItem)sender;

    CollectionEdit dataEdit = new CollectionEdit(collections[(int)item.Tag]);
}
```